# while creating speak function in pyttsx3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

While creating `Jarvis` I had some issues there is no voice given out or no output

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime


def speak(audio):
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say(audio)
        engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
 hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
 if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
            speak("Good Morning!")
 elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
            speak("Good Afternoon!")
 else:
            speak("Good Evening!")

 speak("I am Jarvis Sir. Please tell me how may I help you")
```

But there was output for code written below that
is voice output coming like `hello`, but why not for the above one?

```
import pyttsx3
def speak(audio):
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say(audio)
        engine.runAndWait()
if __name__ == "__main__":
        speak("hello")
```

Please, anyone, help me to understand this
and plz tell me the solution for this
and also I had some issue with sapi5 it will
give something error like

```
line 76, in getProperty   
        return [self._toVoice(attr) for attr in self._tts.GetVoices()]
line 76, in <listcomp>    
        return [self._toVoice(attr) for attr in self._tts.GetVoices()]
line 65, in _toVoice
        return Voice(attr.Id, attr.GetDescription())
line 1753, in GetDescription    
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(4, LCID, 1, (8, 0), ((3, 49),),Locale
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147200966), None)
```

and its code is  like

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)
print(voices[0].id)
engine.SetProperty('voices', voices[0].id)
```

so it is irritating my mind please help

please  adjust if my question is not proper

Comment: you forgot to run `wishMe()`

Comment: on Stackoverflow you should ask one problem on one page - second problem you should ask on new page.